# What's the difference between using belongs_to.attribute and belongs_to[:attribute] in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a chance that the methods below will yield different values, like because of cache or anything?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school

  def first_value
    school.name
  end

  def second_value
    school[:name]
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe `school.name` is implemented under the hood as `school[:name]`, so no there is no difference

Answer (score 4):

Usually, there is no difference between calling an attribute by its name or by using the [`[]`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D) method because the attribute name getter method uses the `[]` method internally. And therefore both return the value of that attribute after it has been typecasted.

But there might be a difference between both methods when the attribute getter method is overwritten in your application. Imagine the method was overwritten like this

```
def name
  self[:name].presence || 'N.N.'
end
```

Then `school.name` would return the school's if the school has a name but it would return the string `'N.N.'` if the name was blank. Whereas `school[:name]` would still return the original value from the database which means it would still return `nil` if the school's name hasn't been set.

Comment: i see. therefore school[:name] is more reliable to get the latest data from the database than school.name syntax.

Comment: @Fernand in general yes however it is worth pointing out that "attributes" are based on column values. Generally this represents the table "columns" but the AR attributes (and accompanying methods) are merely a thin communication layer and is technically DB ignorant so `schools =School.all.select("'My School' as name, 12 as other_attribute")` means `schools.all? {|s| s[:name] ==  'My School' && school.other_attribute == 12} #=> true`. Additionally these "schools" will have no other attributes in this case.

Comment: @Fernand I wouldn't call the `[]` syntax more reliable. It is a lower-level method than calling the attribute by its name. And those two different methods exist for the reason to allow overridden the method. Of course, this depends on your application and the gem you are using, but I would argue that you should always call an attribute by its name and only use the `syntax` when you have a very good reason to do so.